# Convenient notation, or something more?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

A little while ago I happened across a curious formula that blew my mind (no idea what it's called):

$e^{\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)=f(x+1)$

I played around with it a bit and managed to prove it using the Taylor expansion of the exponential and a bit of trickery with the arguments, so I have no issue with it's accuracy.

My question: Is this just convenient notation (to avoid writing out the Taylor series summation) or does it have well defined meaning in and of itself? I tried rearranging and evaluating the derivative inside the exponential for a trial function ($f(x)=x^2$) and it came out with nonsense.

Comment: What does $e^{\frac{d}{dx}}$ mean? You have a number to the power of an operator. What is $\frac{d}{dx}$ being applied to?

Comment: c.f. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131070/algorithm-to-find-exponential-map-of-differential-operators-acting-on-function

Comment: Yes, we can take the exponential (by its Taylor series) of the differential operator and we will get the shift operator.

Comment: Differential operators...right. I know so little about math :(

Comment: Incidentally we use formulas like this all the time in quantum. The shift operator in space is the exponential of momentum which is also d/dx; similar in angular variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much more than convenient notation, but to see what's going on it helps to write it in a more general form as

$$e^{t \frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = f(x + t).$$

This is a version of the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_%28Lie_theory%29) in Lie theory. $\frac{d}{dx}$ can be interpreted as a [vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) on $\mathbb{R}$, and $e^{t \frac{d}{dx}}$ can be interpreted as the [one-parameter group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_group) of diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ given by flowing along the vector field. Passing from one to the other is an important operation in Lie theory, differential geometry, and functional analysis, at the very least.